# How to add ImageView to center of RelativeLayout and let it drag on gesture?

Tags: android, android-imageview, ontouchlistener, android-relativelayout

I'm adding an `ImageView` to `RelativeLayout` via Java code, without declaring `Imageview` in `XML`. Using the following code :

```
final ImageView newImageView= new ImageView(context);
        final RelativeLayout.LayoutParams imgvwDimens = 
                new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 
                         RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

        newImageView.setLayoutParams(imgvwDimens);
       ImageLoader imageLoader = new ImageLoader(context);
       imageLoader.DisplayImage(imageURL, R.drawable.ic_launcher, newImageView);

        newImageView.setScaleType(ScaleType.MATRIX);
        newImageView.setLongClickable(true);
        newImageView.setClickable(true);
```

I want to add the `ImageView` in center of the `RelativeLayout`, so that can be done by:

```
imgvwDimens.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_IN_PARENT, RelativeLayout.TRUE);
```

But if I do so the `ImageView` won't DRAG on touch, so on move I tried removing the `CENTER_IN_PARENT` using :

```
newImageView.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() 
              {

                @Override
                public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) 
                {

                    switch(event.getAction())
                    {
                        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN :
                        {
                            imgvwDimens.removeRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_IN_PARENT);
```

After that I'm able to move the `ImageView`, but on touch it gets relocated to starting of the layout.

Please provide me with helpful code or links. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out, actually solution is pretty simple :)

Following code can be used for centring the ImageView initially, since I'm using RelativeLayout :

```
        imgvwDimens.leftMargin = rl.getWidth()/2;
        imgvwDimens.topMargin = rl.getHeight()/2;
```